# Sequelize select all columns with few columsn with alias

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table with say 10 columns. I want to fetch all columns from the table with 2 columns using alias. Is there any way to do this?

Basically, I want to convert following query to Sequelize

```
select *, processor_txn_id as processor_id from transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add all columns **and** some of them twice with a different name then you can use `include` option in `attributes`:

```js
const results = await Model.findAll({
  attributes: {
    include: [['field_name', 'alias']]
  }
})
```